# Assert - segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, assert

I've got an issue i can't handle so i've thought maybe you can help me. Basically i have a function that receives a char* as a paramater and does some stuff to it(i've checked those steps/functions and they work just fine).If the char* given in the function is ""(i guess NULL), i receive seg fault with assert.
Here is the code:

```
char *computeRNA(char *s)
{
    if (s != NULL && s!= "")
    {
        Lista* l = to_list(s);
        int i;
        l = l->next;
        for(i = 0; i<= lungime(l); ++i)
        {
            if(l->info == 'T')
                l->info = 'U';
            l = l->next;
        }
        char *rna = to_pointer(l);
        return rna;

    }
        return NULL;
}
```

And here is the assert:

```
 char *s;
   s = computeRNA("");
    ASSERT(!strcmp(s, ""), "computeRNA-01");
    free(s);
```

This is a school homework so i can not change assert's code , only the function.**Thanks in advance !**

Comment: `if (s != NULL && s!= "")` --> `if (s && *s)`

Comment: and while the first in @BLUEPIXY's example is a stylistic change, the second certainly isn't.

Comment: You're supposed to return an empty string when given an empty string!

Comment: Applying the `=` operator to a C-"string" (which in fact is a `char`-array) does not what you seem to expect.

Comment: [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: Also what is the `free(s)` doing there? There is no dynamic memory.

Comment: @Lundin: `free(s)` is probably part of a test, implying `computeRNA` must return a pointer returned from `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `ASSERT` that you weren't supposed to be changing, tests that if an empty string is given to `computeRNA` it should also return an empty string:

```
s = computeRNA("");
ASSERT(!strcmp(s, ""), "computeRNA-01");
```

Your code returns null pointer. Also comparing strings needs to be done using `strcmp`, `s == ""` would only compare pointer values that wouldn't be of use here.

Thus I'd start the function with

```
// null pointer was given
if (!s) {
    return calloc(1, 1);
}

// an empty string was given (the first character pointed to b s is the string terminator.)
// to compare explicitly, you need to do `strcmp(s, "")` == 0. `s == ""` is wrong.
if (!*s) {
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a NULL pointer to `strcmp()` as argument. Before the `ASSERT` statement, just check for non-NULL value of `s`. Something like

```
if (s) {
  ASSERT(!strcmp(s, ""), "computeRNA-01");
 }
```

should do the job.

---

EDIT:

In case changing the function *using* the assertion is also not possible, you can modify the `computeRNA()` function to return an empty string, instead of NULL, like

```
char * empty_string = calloc(1,1);
return empty_string;
```

which can later be passed to `free()` in the caller.

Comment: well OP said that asserts are not to be changed, they're checking that the algorithm works as required...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm not sure if I'm suggesting change to the `ASSERT`, rather the function using the assertion. I thought that was allowed.

Comment: case of `return "";` : can't free it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY OK, right... Let me correct my answer then.

Comment: It is the worst of the specification request. (I say to school) (; ・ ;)sad (I alread upvoted)